# disable inline or per method reek code smell detector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reek

Is there a way to disable warning from [`reek`](https://github.com/troessner/reek) gem per method, per line or per block?

What we have for `rubocop` for example

```rb
# suppress warning Use snake_case for method names
def fooBar(baz) # rubocop:disable Naming/MethodName
  baz
end
```

this example will suppress warnings for rubocop, I'm looking something similar for `reek` tool.

```rb
def foo(bar) # reek:disable TooManyStatements
  baz = bar + bar
  # other line
  # more line
  # that produce reek warning
  baz
end
```

In documentation I found that it is configurable only by config file, but that's not what I'm looking for

Comment: I'm not sure which documentation you were looking at; per-method disabling is mentioned [in the README](https://github.com/troessner/reek#source-code-comments).

Comment: There doesn't appear to be support for disabling checks per-line or per-block, however. It only mentions per-project, per-directory, per-file, per-class and per-method.

Comment: @TomLord thanks for that. Yeah somehow I didn't notice that line. This fully answers my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/troessner/reek/blob/master/docs/Smell-Suppression.md#how-to-disable-smell-detection

> There are always the Basic Smell Options you can use in your configuration file.
> But in this document we would like to focus on a completely different way - via special comments.

> A simple example:

```rb
# This method smells of :reek:NestedIterators
def smelly_method(foo)
  foo.each { |bar| bar.each { |baz| baz.qux } }
end
```

> The method smelly_method will not be reported. The general pattern is to put the string `:reek:`, followed by the smell class, in a comment before the method or class.

Comment: that is what I've been looking for, thanks!